# ¿Como obtener mas de 100 datos al realizar un fetch en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando una solicitud a un Api por medio de un fetch, pero al momento que se retornan los datos solo regresan 100, y deberian ser 128 como dice la variable "total_items: 128" y dice "total_pages: 2, current_page: 1", como puedo hacer para acceder a los datos de la otra pagina?

Este es mi codigo:

```
fetch("https://api.tadabase.io/api/v1/data-tables/W4yQkJ6NgP/records", {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "X-Tadabase-App-id": "********", 
            "X-Tadabase-App-Key": "*********",
            "X-Tadabase-App-Secret": "*******"
        }})
        .then(data => data.json())  // convert to json
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
                 
        })    //print data to console
        .catch(err => console.log('Request Failed', err)); // Catch errors
```

[image: Esto es lo que se muestra en consola al imprimir la variable data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muchas veces, cuando realizan llamadas a la API, hay muchos resultados que devolver. Por esa razón, se "paginan" los resultados para asegurar de que las respuestas sean más fáciles de manejar.

Prueba cambiando el parámetro limite `limit` predeterminado agregando en su URL: `../records?limit=128`

```
fetch("https://api.tadabase.io/api/v1/data-tables/W4yQkJ6NgP/records?limit=128", {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        "X-Tadabase-App-id": "********", 
        "X-Tadabase-App-Key": "*********",
        "X-Tadabase-App-Secret": "*******"
    }})
    .then(data => data.json())  // convert to json
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
             
    })    //print data to console
    .catch(err => console.log('Request Failed', err)); // Catch errors
```